# Opengl 3.0+ : How to efficiently draw hierarchical (i.e. chain transform-matrix) meshes with Shader?

Tags: opengl, optimization, shader, parent

**This is a sample 3D scene:-**

Mesh A is the parent of Mesh B. (parent like 3D modeling program Ex.Maya or Blender)

Transformation matrix of Mesh A and B = **MA** and **MB**.

In the old Opengl, Mesh A and Mesh B can be drawn by :-

```
glLoadIdentity();
glMulMatrix(MA);
MeshA.draw();
glMulMatrix(MB);
MeshB.draw();
```

In the new shader Opengl 3.0+, it can be drawn by :-

```
shader.bind();
passToShader(MA);
MeshA.draw();
passToShader(MA*MB);
MeshB.draw();
```

Shader is:-

```
uniform mat4 multiplicationResult;
glVertex = M_multiplicationResult * meshPosition
```

When **MA** is changed in a timestep: In the old way, only **MA** has to be recomputed.  But in the new way, using Shader, the whole **MA x MB** have to be recomputed in CPU.

The problem become severe in the scene in which the hierarchy (parenting) of those Mesh are very high (Ex. 5 levels) and many branches (Ex. one MeshA has many MeshB) , CPU has to recompute the whole **MA x MB x MC x MD x ME** for every related Mesh E, even only single **MA** is changed.

How to optimize it?  Or is it the way to go?

**My poor solutions :-**

1. add more slots in Shader like this:-

   ```
   uniform mat4 MA; 
   uniform mat4 MB; 
   uniform mat4 MC; 
   uniform mat4 MD; 
   uniform mat4 ME;
   glVertex = MA*MB*MC*MD*ME*meshPosition;
   ```

But the shader would never know how many **MX** would be enough.  It is hard-coded, waste GPU for low hierarchy, lower maintainability and don't support more complex scene.

2. use compatibility context - not a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in the new way, using Shader, the whole MA x MB have to be recomputed in CPU.

What did you think that `glMultMatrix` was doing? It too was computing MA x MB. And that computation almost certainly happened on the CPU.

What you want is a matrix stack that works like OpenGL's matrix stack. So... just *write one*. There's nothing magical about what OpenGL was doing. You can write a data type that mirrors OpenGL's matrix operations, then pass it around when you render.

Alternatively, you can just use the C++ stack:

```
void render(const matrix &parent)
{
  matrix me = parent * my_transform;
  passToShader(me);
  my_mesh.draw();
  for(each object)
    object.render(me);
}
```

There, problem solved. Each child of an object receives its parent matrix, which it uses to compute its own full modelview matrix.

---

> I hope to use something faster because they are "relatively-static" objects.

OK, let's do a full performance analysis of this.

The general CPU performance of the code I posted above is doing the exact same number of matrix multiplications as the `glMultMatrix` So your code is as fast now as it used to be (give or take).

So, let's consider the case where you minimize the number of matrix multiples you do on the CPU. Right now, you're doing one matrix multiplication per-object. Instead, let's do no matrix multiplications per object.

So let's say your shader has 4 matrix uniforms (whether a 4 element matrix or just 4 separate uniforms, it doesn't matter). So you're limited to a maximum stack depth of 4, but never mind that now.

This way, you only change the matrices that change. So if a parent matrix changes, the child matrix doesn't have to be recomputed.

OK... so what?

You still have to give that child matrix to the shader. So you're still paying the price of changing program uniform state. You're still uploading 16 floats to the shader per-object.

Not only that, consider what your vertex shader has to do now. It must perform 4 vector/matrix multiplications. And it must do this for *every single vertex* of *every single object*. After all, the shader doesn't know which of those matrices are empty and which ones aren't. So it must assume that they all have data and it must therefore multiply against them all.

So the question is, which is faster:

1. A single matrix multiplication per object on the CPU
2. 3 vector/matrix multiplications **for every vertex** on the GPU (you need to do at least one).

Comment: Thank for explanation about glMultMatrix, upvoted.  That is what I did ... recompute MA*MB for every B recursively (constant MB).  However, I hope to use something faster because they are "relatively-static" objects.  Is it impossible?

Comment: Your explanation is really detailed and complete.  Although I am disappointed with the conclusion, I have to thank for your enlightening answer.